# Generate URL to store image in Datastore Blob

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am a newbie to Python and Google App Engine.
I need to store an image in GAE Datastore (not blobstore - there are lot of examples to store in blobstore and I have got it working in blobstore).

The docs has it as follows:

```
movie = Movie()
...
movie.picture = db.Blob(urlfetch.Fetch(picture_url).content)
movie.put()
```

My question is how do I obtain **picture_url**? I cannot use **create_upload_url** method since this is for Blobstore.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need the images in the datastore in the first place? Are you planning on serving them later?

Comment: Yes. I need to serve them later. And yes, I know I can use Blobstore. But the files are rather small - and I want to test the performance and other behavior characteristics of blobstore vs storing blobs in datastore

Comment: Note that serving a file from the datastore will incur in extra usage. Instance hours + datastore reads, and you won't be able to use the Images API. A n image can be served by calling the method get_serving_url of the Image API.

That said, you can upload your file to blobstore, then read it (See BlobReader), store it in the datastore, and then delete the blob.

Answer (score 0):

This question is phrased in a way no one can answer it because you need to tell people how you intend to get the the image data to begin with.

The code you're using is to download the an image from some URL and save it to you blobstore.  You should be able to use any publicly accessible image url from flickr or facebook or any other website as the url.  You need to decide what url you want to use.

If you want the user to upload the data, then you would need the user to issue a POST request with your image in the multipart/form-data.  You would acceess the data in your request handler's `request.POST` object.  You would not fetch it from a url in that case.

If you're using the Blobstore, GAE automatically parses the POST request data, saves it in the Blobstore, and provides a url for you.  If you're not using the Blobstore, you'll only have the image data in your request object in memory.

Comment: Yes. I can see how it was confusing. Yes I wanted to fetch the image loaded by the user. Got it. I will do as per your suggestion. I got tripped, because when I saw the above code block in the google docs, I thought that for the uploaded images there is a way to obtain url like you can with blobstore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Blob(urlfetch.Fetch(picture_url).content)
```

is for fetching images from another web sites.

if you want to store user-uploaded something, you'd better use

```
data = self.request.get('data')  # where 'data' is the data field from your HTML form
if data :
    db.Blob(data)
```